# React Google/Facebook Login Flow - explained

Tags: reactjs, facebook-login, google-signin

I have to implement Google/Facebook login functionalities in my React app. What I have at the moment are two buttons added (one for G, and other FB) and their corresponding codes are:

```
<GoogleLogin
    className={"googleLoginButton"}
    buttonText=""
    clientId=""
    onSuccess={this.googleResponseOnSuccess}
    onFailure={this.googleResponseOnFailure}
>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} />
</ GoogleLogin>

<FacebookLogin
    appId=""
    autoLoad={false}
    cssClass="facebookLoginButton"
    textButton = ""
    icon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} />}
    fields="name,email,picture"
    callback={this.facebookResponseCallback}
    onClick={this.facebookResponse}
/>
```

Can someone explain entire flow, from clicking on G/FB button (when popup window occurs) and rest, what to do after that? What are `onSuccess` and `onFailure` functions, when they are called for Google login, and what are `callback` and `onClick` for Facebook login? Can anyone provide example how to handle all this process until successful login?

Answer (score 0):

**Google**
Create App at [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/projectcreate?)

Library :[react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login)

```
<GoogleLogin
        clientId="clientKey"
        buttonText="Login"
        onSuccess = { (responseGoogle) => console.log("success",responseGoogle) }
        onFailure = { (responseGoogle) => console.log("error",responseGoogle) }
      />
```

**Note** your react URL must match with URL you mention in **Authorized JavaScript origins** tab on developer console.

**Facebook**
Create at [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/products) my apps tab.

Library [react-facebook-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login) use `appId` in login call like below

```
 <FacebookLogin
    appId="appId here"
    autoLoad={true}
    fields="name,email,picture"
    callback={(res)=>console.log(res)} />
```

Now token it will popup window do login it will `return` token send this token to backend server. 
Server will verify this `token` using app `secrete-key` and will receive logged-in user details. At the server side(in my case explanation is about nodejs as server-side technology), you need to use [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/)